# cin >> writing out of range?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a code

```
char s[5];
cin >> s;
cout << strlen(s);
cout << endl;
cout << s;
```

It works even if I input more than 5 chars, for example "qwertyui". Does it mean that I am using not allocated memory?

Comment: I'm using <iostream> and <cstring>, my IDE is Code::Blocks on Windows.

Comment: Put those details _in the question_ please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, it might still echo correctly if you write more than 5 characters. You're simply writing off the end of the buffer, and just blasting the memory that's next to the memory allocated for `char s[5]`. This is bad for many reasons, including security vulnerabilities. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) for details.

If you can't use `string` (for whatever reason), use `fgets`. See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) for the documentation on `fgets` and how it is used. **NEVER USE** `gets`. It's almost equivalent to what you've done above, see [here for why gets is so dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).

Comment: Thanks, can you tell how to avoid such blasting the memory?

Comment: If you're in C++, I recommend doing what Marcus Muller has suggested. If you're in C land, you can use `fgets` which takes an argument that assures your input can only be so long. If the input is longer, it will only read the number of bytes you specify, and no more.

Comment: Thank you, it's what I need

Comment: Great! Glad to help. I'd change the tag of the question to C instead of C++ if that's the case. Despite their similarities, they are also different :).

Comment: I'm using C++ but I can't use <string> because it's the homework and I can use only concrect libs.

Comment: If your homework is to write C++, then fgets is *not* the answer. It's a C relict, that's in C++ for compatibity reasons only.

Comment: Not being able to use `<string>` but `<iostream>` is OK? That is kind of contradicting itself. They are part of the same library, the C++ standard library.

Answer (score 2):

```
strlen(s)
```

is *something*, but has nothing to do with `5`. `strlen` applies to C strings, which *are* char arrays, but their length is defined as the numbers of characters until the first zero byte happens.

Now, `cin` in your second line *cannot know* how long your `char[]` is, so it just accepts as much input as there is. You **must never** use char buffers for input you don't know is well-formed. What you're seeing is a *buffer overflow* in action. Writing over memory that doesn't belong to any variable you allocated results in *undefined behaviour*, so your program might just work, crash with e.g. a segfault (accessing memory that the OS never gave you), or overwriting existing part's of your processes' memory, or … just do anything, because it's really *undefined*.

So, you're writing C++, not C. just

```
string s;
cin >> s;
cout << s.length()
<< endl
<< s;
```

to avoid dealing with the (very dangerous) C strings.

Comment: Thank you, I'm just doing my homework where I can't use <string>. I know that strlen(s) is searching '\0'. Is it any easy way to control overflow via 'cin', or I must input it char by char via 'for' and 'getchar()'?

Comment: @Pavel: what you can and cannot use **must be in your question**. Please update your question.